# Calling PHP function inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

In my project I need to call PHP function inside Javascript file. I have a file called `Test.php`. Inside this file I have function called `getValue()`.This function will return some value:

```
<? php
function getValue()
{
echo json_encode('84');
}
?>
```

Also, I have Javascript file called `myScript.js`. Inside this file I want to call `detVale();` and save the return value in `var knobValue`. I tried this but it did not work

```
var knobValue;

$.post('Test.php', function(result) {
     knobValue=result;
}, 'json');


$.get('Test.php', function(result) {
  knobValue=result;
});

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Test.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
         knobValue=result;
      }
 });
```

Comment: Try adding some error handling to your AJAX call in example 3. You can add `statusCode: { 404: function(){alert('404');}, 500: function(){alert('500');}}` to start. This is part of how you can identify what the error is.

Comment: I tried what you said, at first I got 404 error then I changed the url. the error stop appearing but still the code does not work.

Comment: Can you expand upon how it doesn't work?

Comment: After I get the information from the php I want to show the result in input text field. $(".dial-div").append('<div class="inline" name="'+item.options_index+'"><div class="m-r-md inline"><input type="text" value="'+knobValue+'" class="dial m-r-sm"  data-width="85" data-height="85" disabled="true" /></div><h5>'+this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value+'</h5></div>');. Put I got NAN.

Answer (score 6):

My guess on the limited information provided is you've not called the `getValue()` function.

```
<?php
    function getValue()
    {
        echo json_encode('84');
    }

    getValue();
?>
```

Comment: I tried that put still no result. What kind of information do you need to help me?

Comment: In your browsers development console does the ajax call have any data returned?

Comment: No it does not have any data